# Photo app stuck on "restoring..." after iOS upgrade

Tags: iphone, photos.app, ios

On my iPhone 4, after I updated the software to iOS 5 beta 6 by restoring it and importing a backup of my data, the Photo app is stuck with a spinning wheel and the "restoring" message:
[image: photo app]

Everything is working correctly otherwise, all my albums, events, faces and places have been synced to the phone and the photos are showing without problems.

I'm wondering what the "restoring" message means, it's stuck on "0 of 444" since yesterday.

Comment: Voting to close, this is about beta software, so off-topic on this site, see the [faq].

Answer (score 2):

It's having issues reading the database cache for the Photos app I think. Unfortunately the only good way to fix it that I know of is to do a full reset restore run again (I've had to do a few too many of those recently so I know that pain).

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Apple Dev Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/community/ios/ios5beta). iOS 5 is still under NDA, unfortunately. I'm sure someone there has spoken on it though.